# Simple Joomla plugin not working on frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, content-plugin

I have a simple Joomla 3 plugin that works fine on backend for resizing images when uploading from multimedia manager:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class PlgContentProcesador extends JPlugin
{
    protected $allowedMimeTypes = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');


    public function onContentAfterSave($context, $article, $isNew)
    {
        if ($context == 'com_media.file') {
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('Filepath: ' . $article->filepath);
            if ($article->type == 'image/jpeg' or $article->type == 'image/png') {
                $orig_image = new JImage($article->filepath);
                // 750 will be set accordind to image ratio depending on 1000
                $resized_image = $orig_image->resize(1000, 750, true, JImage::SCALE_INSIDE);
                $resized_image->toFile($article->filepath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to work the same on upload frontend in article submission, but when changing the context to com_content.form, nothings works. The variable $article seems not retrieve any data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Though not an issue for this snippet, I would urge you to not use `or` in conditions with multiple expressions because `or` has [the lowest precedence of all operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and can sometimes cause buggy/unexpected problems.  Welcome to JSE and please take our [tour].

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$article`? It should be an instance of `Joomla\CMS\Table\Content`. It's not going to have the same properties as a media file.

Comment: How can I check that value? I tried with var_dump but nothing showing up.

Comment: You need to `exit` after `var_dump()` because a redirect is performed afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can see that the `$article` variable doesn't contain the path, so I'll try another approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to pass the `$article` parameter in as a reference.  Add a `&` before the `$article` variable in the function call.

So, to change...

```
public function onContentAfterSave($context, $article, $isNew)
```

...to...

```
public function onContentAfterSave($context, &$article, $isNew)
```

Comment: Tried, but not working.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a bit more of a think